# ActiveRecord unknown column

Tags: ruby, activerecord, has-many-through, mysql2

I ran into a little problem I have a has_many through relationship here is the code for the models

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :followings, :through => :friendships, :foreign_key => "followed_id"
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :following, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "followed_id"
end
```

now at the console I can type u = User.first and then u.friendships.first.following this gives me the first user u is following, but when I type u.friendships.last.following I get this error

the SELECT statement from u.friendships.first.following

```
Friendship Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `friendships`.* FROM `friendships` WHERE `friendships`.`user_id` = 208 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 209 LIMIT 1
```

and the SELECT statement from u.friendships.last.following

```
Friendship Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `friendships`.* FROM `friendships` WHERE `friendships`.`user_id` = 208 ORDER BY `friendships`.`` DESC LIMIT 1
```

```ruby
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'friendships.' in 'order
clause': SELECT  `friendships`.* FROM `friendships`  WHERE `friendships`.`user_id` = 208
ORDER BY `friendships`.`` DESC LIMIT 1
```

if I then run u.friendships and then u.friendships.last.following again, I don't get the error anymore, why is that?

Comment: guessing that the call to u.friendships ends up in a cache so that when you call u.friendships.last it just needs to get to the last item in the previously retreived list.

Comment: I have edited my post a bit, so you can see the SELECT statements, i wonder, why there is a difference between the two of them, why is ActiveRecord.last using an ORDER BY clause if it can only return one record?

Comment: did you try specifying a column to order by in your query?
`u.friendships.order(:created_at).first.following`
`u.friendships.order(:created_at).last.following`
\n Or try a default scope in your model:
`default_scope order('created_at DESC')`

Comment: I believe activerecord uses ORDER BY because it needs to know what you consider the 'last' record.

Comment: it's not my query, it's the auto generated query from ActiveRecord, the SELECT queries you see are the ones from the console output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres my sql output for `friendships`, straight from your code on **Rails 3.2.9 / postgresql**:

```
# u.friendships.first.following
Friendship Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1

# u.friendships.first.following
Friendship Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY "friendships"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

So for some reason for me, `id` is getting picked up automatically in `ORDER BY "friendships"."id"` and it works.  Maybe your problem has something to do with your DB?

```
#Statements used to create the db for reproducing this problem
CREATE TABLE users (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE friendships (
    id            SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id       integer
    followed_id   integer 
);
```

Comment: stupid me I did exclude the id column at friendship table creation, because there was a misunderstanding between has_and_belongs_to_many and has_many through ^^

Comment: ahhh yeh that would do it.  I'm guessing that you didn't let rails generate those migrations for you?

Comment: oh I did let rails generate the migration, but I put :id => false to the create_table statement ;)

Comment: yeahh, i find that has_and_belongs_to_many is only useful when you only when the only data you need to store about the associate multiple models is the fact that the association exists.  You can't use ActiveRecord to queries the habtm table since there no `id` or more importantly a `Class` defining the model!